# Problem with creating an edit box in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Well, I have a problem when creating fields for data editing. The problem is that when editing, all fields with the product name are activated instead of one specific. I know the problem is because I only have one variable responsible for enabling the edit box, but creating more variables will not solve the problem because then there may be thousands of such records.

HTML:

```
<ul>
                <li v-for="product in products" class="single-product" v-bind:key="product.id_product">
                    <i style="color:#df4a49;padding:5px;" class="fa-solid fa-xmark fa-xl" @click="deleteProduct(product.id_product)"></i>
                    <p class="product-name"><i @click="enableEditing(product.name)" class="fas fa-edit" style="color:#0575ff;padding-right:5px;"></i>
                        <span v-if="!editing">{{product.name}}</span> <span v-if="editing"> <input v-model="tempValue" class="input"/>
                            <button @click="disableEditing"> Edit</button>
                            <button @click="saveEdit"> Save</button>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <span class="product-localization"><span><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:#0575ff;padding-right:5px;"></i>Lokalizacja: </span>{{produkt.lokalizacja}}</span> <span class="product-key"><span><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:#0575ff;padding-right:5px;"></i>Klucz: </span>{{product.key}}</span>
                    <hr />
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Data:

```
editing:false,
tempValue: null,
```

methods:

```
enableEditing: function(tempProductName){
    this.tempValue = tempProductName;
    this.editing=true;
  },
  disableEditing: function(){
      this.tempValue = null;
      this.editing = false;
    },
    saveEdit: function(){
      this.value = this.tempValue;
      this.disableEditing();
    }
```

Comment: Create a separate component for each product. That would be the cleanest solution. But if you want to do it quick and dirty, have `editing` be the id of the product being edited.

Comment: @thomas Dirty way sounds good. Can you provide me with any example how to make `editing` an id of the product?

Comment: Simply assign values of type Number to the `editing` variable instead of Boolean values.